# Why are the test results listed twice in the console output?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

This is how my test results are currently being output to the console. Notice how "Run options... Running: ..." and "Finished in..." are both listed twice.

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 8515
Run options: --seed 3074

# Running:

Run options: --seed 3074

# Running:

2018-02-14T14:46:14-06:00 - Changing from waiting_to_be_circulated to offered_to_user (event: offer)
..........

Finished in 1.059601s, 4.7188 runs/s, 4.7188 assertions/s.

5 runs, 5 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips


Finished in 1.059780s, 4.7180 runs/s, 4.7180 assertions/s.
5 runs, 5 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

**Any idea where I can check to see what may be causing the output to duplicate?** I'm running Rails 5.1.5 and Ruby 2.4.1. Please let me know if you'd like to see any more information, I'm happy to provide it!

Here is my test_helper.rb

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'

require 'minitest/autorun' 

require 'minitest/reporters'
# Minitest::Reporters.use!(
#   Minitest::Reporters::ProgressReporter.new(:color => true),
#   ENV,
#   Minitest.backtrace_filter
# )

# Integrate AASM gem's custom testing methods into minitest
require 'aasm/minitest'

require 'fileutils' # Used below in setting up CarrierWave

... <various CarrierWave settings also here> ...    

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include ApplicationHelper
  include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  # Log in as a particular user
  def log_in_as(user, password: 'password', remember_me: '1')
    post login_path, params: { session: { email: user.email,
                                          password: password,
                                          remember_me: remember_me } }
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you also tell us what are you typing into the terminal to achieve this? :)

Comment: Sure @Taryn! Single tests with the standard `$ rails test test/models/task_test.rb`, etc  All tests with `$ rails test`

Comment: Odd. I've not seen that method of running a single test-file before. usually I'd write `ruby test/models/task_test.rb` OR `rails test TEST=test/models/task_test.rb` (but I'll admit it's been a while - I use rspec at work)

Comment: Thank you for giving it a look @Taryn! *high five*  Spent a little time with it today and It looks to have something to do with the minitest-reporters gem, like it's somehow causing the test to run "within" the originating test's output (that's maybe why their outputs are nested like that). I got around it for the time being by disabling the gem altogether. Will update my question if I ever discover a fix for it.

Comment: w00t. How odd. Glad you have a temporary-fix... (or at least can pinpoint where it's going weird). good luck with a better solution.